# Difference in Difference estimator using PSM and time varying covariates

Tags: multiple-regression, panel-data, difference-in-difference, generalized-did

Which is the most appropriate DID estimator when we are studying the impact of certain policies on  firms across different countries where some firms adopted the policy in every country at diiferent times. I was reading paper by (callaway and santanna 2020) but problem with this paper is that it cant handle time varying covariates which vary after treatment exogenously or affected by treatment.

Comment: Welcome. Could you provide a reference to their paper?

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304407620303948